# Location still monitoring after locationManager = nil and stopUpdatingLocation called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm trying a lot of things to stop the location update of my app but nothing seems work…

What I do (regard of the post : [StopUpdatingLocation method not working for iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017587/stopupdatinglocation-method-not-working-for-ios5)) :

```
// Initialise my locationManager and start monitoring :
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

// .. Some code to use the coordinates that locationManager gives me.

// To stop monitoring :
locationManager = nil;
```

You have to know I placed `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` in the method :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

So the location is updated only 1 time (btw tell me if it's a good idea…).

I also tried to place `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` just before `locationManager = nil;` in the main code, but the blue dot that gives me my location is still moving on my map in both cases…

I also set a timer which print the `locationManager` object in the console, and it gives me `(null)` meanwhile the blue dot is still moving on my iPhone 5 so I don't understand that…

Or maybe the dot is still moving because of another thing, but not because of locationManager update ?

I'm certainly missing something but I don't get what :/.

Thanks for ideas and help.

Comment: // Initialise my locationManager and start monitoring :
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

// .. Some code to use the coordinates that locationManager gives me.

// To stop monitoring :
locationManager = nil;

is all of this in one method? that would be wrong.

Comment: Yes it is..? What's wrong ? :/

Comment: because location manager is already assigned nil. you will not be able to access it anymore in the callback locationManager:didUpdateLocations: so if you placed [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] in the callback, it would have no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**One possibility**: The blue dot moving on your map is because you set the MKMapView's `showsUserLocation` to YES. It will track until you set it to NO.

**Another possibility**: This line is wrong:

```
locationManager = nil;
```

That does *not* stop monitoring, but it *does* cause you to be unable to refer to the location manager, so now you *can't* stop monitoring! Cut that line.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I thought that `showsUserLocation` was just the "display" property of the blue dot of the MKMapView so for me, it doesn't mean location monitoring is stopped. So for me, set `showsUserLocation` to NO will not stop the background monitoring task. I'm wrong ?

And I don't understand why the blue dot is still moving if the location is not updated :). The location should stay the same because of no update of the coordinates values. I'm wrong again ?

Comment: Read the docs. "*As long as this property is YES*, the map view *continues to track the user’s location* and *update* it periodically."

Comment: Ok so it's impossible to keep the blue dot displayed without updating location periodically. That's what I wanted : keep the blue dot on the last updated coordinates, even after shuting down the location tracking. So I guess I have now to import my own blue dot png picture and set it into a new annotation with the last location coordinates.

Comment: What is the way in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem that even after I placed the code

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
locationManager=nil;
```

my application was using GPS service which was un-necessarily consuming battery power. the solution for this problem is to turn off the showUserLocation property of MKMapView .

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
```

Since the MKMapView keeps on using your `GPS service` even if the `LocationManager` is nil.

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use this lines of code

```
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
self.locationManager = nil;
```

Thanks!