# Background location service tracking not stopping when i "OFF" the UISwitch

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, background-process

Am using UISwitch to turn "ON" and "OFF" the the location services. When i Switch "ON" the UISwitch the location services start to to track teh location. I can come out the app and location services are running good. My problem is when i switch "OFF" the tracking and move to any `View Controller` the location tracking still in "ON" state and its not stopping the tracking. below is my code.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    latDeg = location.coordinate.latitude;
    longDeg = location.coordinate.longitude;
}

-(IBAction)startTracking:(id)sender{
 if(startTrackingButton.on){
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:startTrackingButton.on forKey:@"switchValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:startTrackingButton.on forKey:@"switchValue"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
  [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
 }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [startTrackingButton setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switchValue"]];
   locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   [locationManager setDelegate:self];
   [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
   [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cab you test with the debugger to see if the line [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; gets executed?

Comment: I verified with the else part of `-(IBAction)startTracking:(id)sender{` above code it gets executed but the next line again it starts to track

Comment: Check this out, probably your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469741/why-self-locationmanager-stopupdatinglocation-doesnt-stop-location-update

Comment: i tried with the answer it stopped in that page correctly but when i kept the UISwitch "ON" and move to next page or previous one in stops tracking

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `startTrackingButton` is actually a `UISwitch`. If that is the case, you should be checking the `isOn` property.

```
if (startTrackingButton.isOn) {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:startTrackingButton.on forKey:@"switchValue"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
} else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:startTrackingButton.on forKey:@"switchValue"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```